# LNK2005 and LNK2019 in a big project

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am working in a Big project and I have to use AD (Automatic differentiation), so I choose to start with adept Library, what is essential to know that I have to put adept_source.h in the main file and adept.h in any other file (one contains the definitions and the other contains the declarations, grosso modo).

The problem is I have a big project with different solutions inside (I'm using Visual Studio), and I don't know how to find the equivalent of main.cpp file, when I include adept_source.h in different solutions I get the error LNK2005 (Already defined). in the other hand, when I don't include it, it shows me the LNK2019 (is not defined).

Comment: I recommend searching the internet for "lnk2005" and "lnk2019".  There are already answers to these issues.

Comment: Did you read the *adept* documentation?  Are there any forums or groups for *adept* Users?

Comment: Do they provide a sample application or a unit test app?  Compare them to what you are doing.

Comment: hi Thomas, I already have those answers, but my principal problem is to find the main file in a very big project with so many solutions inside, to include the adept_source.h. for you second Question, I have the user guide and I already used adept in a small project (with a main.cpp and the two other header file) and it works...

Comment: Hi Dave, yes I use the two file to create a simple test and it works but when I want to integrate it in the big project I fail in every single time.

Comment: Download a grep-type application and search for all "main."  Or try this with Visual Studio's "Find in Files" but that might not be able to search every folder you're including.